# haml pull-right as a second class not working when followed by an if

Tags: haml

So I have this piece of .erb code I want to translate to .haml. (some says haml is faster, I think i'm still strugling within the learning curve ;) )

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
      <% if current_page?(webservices_path) %>
      <li class="submenu_links_current">
      <% else %>
      <li class="submenu_links">
      <% end %>
        <%= link_to webservices_path do %>
          <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;"></i>
          Webservices
        <% end %>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The nearest haml translation I have atm :

```
.row
  .col-md-12
    %ul.list-inline.pull-right
    - if current_page?(webservices_path)
      %li.submenu_links_current
        = link_to webservices_path do
          %i.fa.fa-home{"aria-hidden" => "true", "style" => "color: white;"}
          Webservices
    - else
      %li.submenu_links
        = link_to webservices_path do
          %i.fa.fa-home{"aria-hidden" => "true", "style" => "color: white;"}
          Webservices
```

I have two problems with this haml right now.

.pull-right is not applied to ul if there's an if statement between ul and li.

I also found that this following more factorized code doesn't work since while currently on webservices_path, link_to webservices_path is not displayed.

```
.row
  .col-md-12
    %ul.list-inline.pull-right
    - if current_page?(webservices_path)
      %li.submenu_links_current
    - else
      %li.submenu_links
        = link_to webservices_path do
          %i.fa.fa-home{"aria-hidden" => "true", "style" => "color: white;"}
          Webservices
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```haml
.row
  .col-md-12
    %ul.list-inline.pull-right
      %li{:class => (current_page?(webservices_path) ? 'submenu_links_current' : 'submenu_links')}
        = link_to webservices_path do
          %i.fa.fa-home{"aria-hidden" => "true", "style" => "color: white;"}
          Webservices
```

Note the two `li` have been combined into a single element, setting the class using the `class` element of the hash rather than the dot syntax. This removes the duplication and of the `link_to`. Also it is indented under the `ul` (in your code the `if` statements are at the same level, so the `li`s won’t be children of it).

Comment: Thank you @matt. Working just as expected. Clear explanations too ;)